# Make grails codec stop splitting long string into chunks

Tags: string, grails, groovy, codec

When using a grails codec with the automatic .encodeAsCodecName, I've noticed that instead of just calling the codecs's encode() function once for the whole string, it splits the string into multiple smaller ones and calls encode on each one... (This of course happens when the string is larger than certain size, ~couple Kb).

Can this be disabled? How is this even a feature, codecs are supposed to be used for processing all kinds of text, what if a codec wants to parse html tags and remove/add some, this splitting will for sure mess up the syntax...